# collection view moving cell down

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is my first post and although this seems like something easy I just cant seem to find the fix. I am trying to move the cell on the left up to match the top of the cell on the right. Maybe I need to use a different controller however I thought I would ask before going back to the drawing board

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = false
    collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
    collectionView?.register(LeagueCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 24
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 24
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath.item == 0 {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 0.87, height: 70)
    } else if indexPath.item == 1 {
        return CGSize(width: 120, height: 120)
    } else if indexPath.item == 2 {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 0.47, height: view.frame.height * 0.6)
    } else if indexPath.item == 3 {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 0.3, height: view.frame.height * 0.41)
    }

    return CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 24, left: 24, bottom: 24, right: 24)
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! LeagueCell
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have better understanding about `UICollectionView ` `DataSource` and `Delegate` methods and how it works.and what exact UI change you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can change the Y of the cell on the left and set it same as the cell on the right:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! LeagueCell

    if(indexPath.row == 1){

        let indexPathOfRightCell = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
        let cellOnTheRight = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPathOfRightCell) as! LeagueCell
        cell.frame.origin.y = cellOnTheRight.frame.origin.y

    }

    return cell
}
```

It’s not the perfect or standard solution, but it may work in your case.

Comment: Thank you! This did actually work. I think in the long run it may be better to make a custom layout but its a good start. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using UICollectionViewFlowLayout here.

This is the behaviour of that layout.

If you want to create a layout that does what you are looking for the best thing would be to create it yourself.

There are many tutorials about creating your own layouts. Depending on exactly what you want the layout could be very different.

They all pretty much work the same way apart from the `prepare` method that actually calculates everything.

Comment: I think that this may be the best route. I had no idea the flow layout was like that. Thank you for clearing up my confusion! Thank you for the response!